# Best solution to display a web page with a video embedded

Tags: video

We realized a webpage to display some promo videos and the news for a medical center: http://www.centromedicoparioli.it/presentation.php
Videos and news elements are in the same web page that switch from videos to the news using javascript.
We would like to display it on a videowall so we bought a monitor and a Raspberry.

We started installing Raspbian, but we found that there is no way to watch a video in a web page (HTML5 or Flash) using any type of browser (Midori, Iceweasel and Chrome) : when you play the video CPU usage jumps to 100%.
We tested a simple video with VLC and we obtained the same result.

So we tried with XMBC (XBian and OPENElec) but they have no web browser (only a text web browser) and to configure all the environment to have it (http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23051) seems really hard.

We tried FirefoxOS as well but it doesn't start at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you play video in a Pi, you need to use a movie player that uses the Pi's GPU.  The CPU doesn't have enough horsepower to decode video itself.  Try using omxplayer on the command line to see if it can play your video.

Comment: Are you using the latest firmware (`rpi-update` comes with Raspbian) and have the device overclocked into Turbo mode (1 GHz instead of 0.7 GHz)? This gives you also some more speed.